# Django flatpages

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-flatpages

I am using Django flatpages and would like to implement some logic in a template based on a user session variable.

eg.

```
{% if session.my_var %}
    YES
{% else %}
    NO
{% endif %}
```

Problem is that session object is not defined in flatpage context.

Comment: What is your question? What issue are you having?

Comment: so, what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSOR` which is then used by the `RequestContext` (see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext)).

```
def session(request):
    return { 'session': request.session }
```

Comment: Great, that exactly what I am looking for (as I don't see session if flatpage module sources)

Comment: @AlanHarper: I just updated my answer as the template tag was a more elaborate solution. Django's flatpages uses a RequestContext so you can create a template context processor to add variables to the context.

Comment: tnx, btw - may be you remember if it's possible to include one flatpage into another? (like a placeholder common for several pages)? tnx

Comment: @I don't think that's possible as one page could then consist of multiple `FlatPage` model objects. But you can still include the templates as normal Django templates using `include`.